# Condiconal to send params via $emit according to the route you are VUE.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I would like to know how I would do to create a conditional if according to the route that the user is

```
    refreshData (){
      var params = {};
      for (var key in this.filters) {
        if (this.filters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (
            this.filters[key] == 0 ||
            this.filters[key] == false ||
            (this.filters[key] && this.filters[key] !== '')
          ) {
            params[key] = mapFilter(this.filters[key]);
          }
        }
      }
      if (url == osdata) {
        this.$root.$emit('refreshData', params);
      }
      if(url == bidata){
          this.$root.$emit('refereshBi', params);
   }
```

I tried to introduce in the end, some if, but it didn't work and it wouldn't be the right way, as it would?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Vue 2 and Vue-router for routing. In this case you can get current route information via this.$route, for example:

```
if (this.$route.path == '/page') { 
    
}
```

this.$route contains the following properties:

```
{ 
   name: 'Name of the route',
   path: '/path/to/route', 
   params: { /* object with route parameters */ },
   query: { /* everything after the question mark in url (example: #/page?id=1&a=b) */} 
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, but you seem to be asking how you could create a conditional with the current route. There are better strategies so you don't have to know the current route url, but you didn't ask about it.